# Jquery setting opacity issue

Tags: jquery, css, opacity

```
$("html").fadeTo("slow",0.5); 
OR 
$("html").css({ 'opacity':'0.5' });
```

Why does either of these scripts whiten the page? I need it to become darker, no whiter, and usually that's what opacity does but not here...

How can I set a black opacity to my html with jquery?

Comment: What is the background color? opacity refers to the transparency of something.  1 is completely opaque, meaning no transparency, and 0 is completely transparent, meaning you'll see whatever is in the background - if you have a white background it will get "whiter" and if you have a black background it will get "blacker"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add a black div and fade it in on top of everything

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div id="cover"></div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
#cover {
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    background-color:#000;
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    z-index:99999999;
}
```

JQuery:

```
$('#cover').fadeTo("slow",0.5);
```

Here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/AlienWebguy/GM2Z6/2/